DateRangePicker Auto-Select Date without Apply, but Not OnLoad
I am using https://www.daterangepicker.com.
I want to be able to select a date without using .on("apply".  This is very easy with autoApply and autoUpdateInput, BUT... I do not want it to show the startDate value when the page loads.  onLoad triggers the update and shows it.  I want to bypass that part and have it blank onLoad unless there is a value="xxxxxx" for the input box (if there is a value, it should show like normal - this is the reason I cannot just make it .val("") on page load).  It's like there needs to be another setting to skipOnload or something.
I have the following code.  Any help would be appreciated!
$(".CheckInOutDate").daterangepicker(
{
    todayHighlight: true,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    //autoApply: true,
    //autoUpdateInput: true,
    startDate: '01/01/2025',
    locale:
    {
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    }
}).on("apply.daterangepicker", function (e, picker) {
    picker.element.val(picker.startDate.format(picker.locale.format));
});


I figured out a hack workaround for this issue where even if there is a value="xxxx" the autoUpdateInput will overwrite the value when the page loads with the startDate or minDate. Very annoying.
Now I check if I am adding data (i know that value="") then I just call $(".CheckInOutDate").val(""); after the daterangepicker call. This wipes the date that it added onload incorrectly.
This is something that should be fixed on the picker though. I do not see any other way to fix it currently, unless I am missing something...
